# Nltk Classify - Naive Bayes displaying an incredible accuracy of 0.996

Tags: text, classification, text-classification

I am facing with a weird issue. I use NaiveBayesClassifier from nltk.classify to categorize text and my problem is that it is displaying an incredible accuracy of 0.9966. I am sure this cannot be real, still I see no errors in my code. My input is huge, 40.000 sentences used for training and 80.000 used for testing.

I am building a set of train features made up of all the negative/positive/neutral labeled training text

```
  trainFeats = negFeats + posFeats + neutralFeats
```

and a set of test features made up of all the negative/positive/neutral labeled training text

```
  testFeats = negFeats + posFeats + neutralFeats
```

Afterwards I train the classifier on the trainFeats

```
  classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainFeats)
```

and test it on all the testFeats

```
  print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testFeats)
```

Is this a normal result, should I take things for granted? Because it behaves strikingly good. Thanks!

Comment: your question is very vague as we don't know your input nor do we know your code.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I edited my question, hope it's more clear now.

Comment: So you're using the same data for training/testing?

Comment: @qqilihq No, it's different data.

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to say what the problem is.  Are you using the same data for training as for testing?  If so, this is a classic case of overlearning.

Comment: How is the class distribution? (# of neg/pos/neutral instances?)

Comment: Training: 20 000 pos/ 10 000 neutral/ 5 000 neg
Testing: 40 000 pos / 20 000 neutral / 10 000 neg